# Testing a controller which includes ActionController::Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, eventsource

I have a controller which includes the Rails `ActionController::Live` module. I am displaying the contents of a logfile, which is being read using `FileTail` gem, and using `SSE` from `ActionController::Live` like so:

```
class LogsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def live
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: 'queries')
    File.open(logfile_location) do |log|
      log.extend(File::Tail)
      log.interval = 1
      log.backward(10)
      log.tail {|line| sse.write line}
    end
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.info "Error Message:: #{e.message}"
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end
```

I want to test the `live` action using `Rspec`. This is what I currently have:

```
before { get :live }
it { expect(response.headers['Content-Type']).to eq("text/event-stream") }
after {response.stream.close unless response.stream.closed? }
```

if I don't have the line with `after` in place, the spec passes but it just keeps on listening  and the connection is never closed, hence the specs never finish and you have to kill them manually.

If I have the `after` line, it passes sometimes, but most of the times it throws an exception, and the specs fail.

```
fatal:
   No live threads left. Deadlock?
```

Is there a way I can make this work? Maybe there's a specific way this has to be tested which am unable to find anywhere.

Comment: Based on the docs it looks like the request is moved to a separate thread (off the main thread) which means you'd probably want to follow something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27383737/3109182

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially two problems in your application that stops you to test your code.

1) You are using old version of rails that does not include [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a640da454fdb9cd8806a1b6bd98c2da93f1b53b9) fix(rails 5+ includes it)

2) Obviously, you are using `File::Tail` in the way when your code runs without point of exit. I mean that this:

```rb
File.open(logfile_location) do |log|
  log.extend(File::Tail)
  log.interval = 1
  log.backward(10)
  log.tail {|line| sse.write line}
end
```

runs forever.

So, you need simply stub `File::Tail` part that is responsible for running the code forever or modify your code accordingly(`log.return_if_eof = Rails.env.test?` will help).

Tested on rails 5.2.2. This code works:

```rb
describe "#live" do
  subject { process :live, method: :get }  

  its(:body) { is_expected.to include(file_content) } # file_content is content of your file
  its(:body) { is_expected.to include('event: queries') }
  its(:headers) { is_expected.to match(hash_including('Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream')) }
end
```